# Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D://foldername//filename.jpg

Tags: html, jsp

Actually I have to upload 20000 images into mysql database if I store all images to Mysql database as Blob type the performance is reduced and It will slow down if we upload other images if required.To avoid this problem I am storing all images into folder and their path's into mysql database table.and retriving these images with pagination .
now data is showing in table but images are not displaying.

```
String sb1 = new String("file://");
String sb2=new String(user.getPlaceImage());

out.println("<td><img src="+sb1.concat(sb2)+"  width='70' height='50' /></td>");
```

If there is any alternative way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Are the images to be displayed only on the server/computer where they are stored, or anybody connecting to the URL remotely (LAN or internet) should be able to view the pictures? With the above example, images are available on the machine running the JSP only.

Comment: what is your application context? ie. localhost:8080/context/?

Comment: images are stored on local machine ie d:\\folodername\\filename.jpg

Comment: yes my application context is localhost:8080/webcontent/controller

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic alternative technique that I use to serve images to users:
Create a folder outside your website root so users won't have direct access to the files using HTTP. Let's say you already have a database table that contains URI to all the images. Create a interface file, for instance: getimage.jsp?id=42 that serves user the requested image file. Also, if you are storing relative URLs in the database you need to be extra careful because you might be trying to read the file from a wrong path in relation to your JSP file that's trying to access the image.

Comment: images are displaying on IE but mozila firefox doesnt support that image.

Comment: What kind of image file type is it?

Comment: i have displyed imagePath also.that i was getting in the output.but the problem is that only images is not loading from local resources.

Comment: is there any browser compatiblity issues.

Comment: Any luck on this?